# Some Data Points not Appearing on PyPlot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a chart that shows the `Observation` data points, along with the corresponding prediction.

However, as I am plotting, the red `Observation` dots are not appearing on my plot; and I am unsure as to why.

They do appear when I run the following in another line:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,6))
plt.plot(testY, 'r.', markersize=10, label=u'Observations')
plt.plot(predictedY, 'b-', label=u'Prediction')
```

But the code that I am using to plot does not allows them to show up:

```
def plotGP(testY, predictedY, sigma):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,6))
    plt.plot(testY, 'r.', markersize=10, label=u'Observations')
    plt.plot(predictedY, 'b-', label=u'Prediction')
    x = range(len(testY))
    plt.fill(np.concatenate([x, x[::-1]]), np.concatenate([predictedY - 1.9600 * sigma, (predictedY + 1.9600 * sigma)[::-1]]),
             alpha=.5, fc='b', ec='None', label='95% confidence interval')


subset = results_dailyData['2010-01':'2010-12']
testY = subset['electricity-kWh']
predictedY = subset['predictedY']
sigma = subset['sigma']

plotGP(testY, predictedY, sigma)
```

My current plot, where the red Observation points are not appearing.
[image: The red Observation data points are not appearing]

The plot when I run the plotting code in it's own line.  I'd like these dots and the blue line to appear in the plot above:
[image]

Comment: It would help to have a [mcve] available.

Comment: Have you checked if the red dots are behind the blue area? If so, you can change their [`zorder`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider the following example, where the two cases with and without the fill function from the question are compared.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import pandas as pd


def plotGP(ax, testY, predictedY, sigma, showfill=False):
    ax.set_title("Show fill {}".format(showfill))
    ax.plot(testY, 'r.', markersize=10, label=u'Observations')
    ax.plot(predictedY, 'b-', label=u'Prediction')
    x = range(len(testY))
    if showfill:
        ax.fill(np.concatenate([x, x[::-1]]), np.concatenate([predictedY - 1.9600 * sigma, (predictedY + 1.9600 * sigma)[::-1]]),
             alpha=.5, fc='b', ec='None', label='95% confidence interval')

x = np.linspace(-5,-2)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=len(x)))
sigma = 2

df = pd.DataFrame({"y" : y}, index=x)

fig, (ax, ax2)  =plt.subplots(2,1)
plotGP(ax,df.y, df.y, sigma, False)
plotGP(ax2, df.y, df.y, sigma, True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

As can be seen, the `plot` curves may sit at completely different positions in the diagram, which would depend on the index of the dataframe.